# Identify Queries causing space issue

Tags: sql-server

I have around 1 TB of space for my tempdb in my SQL Server 2014.

In the morning I see some alerts saying the "tempdb was Full". I know there are many queries run over night and there are few queries which create a lot of temp tables and temp variables in tempdb. In morning I do not see any queries running and the tempdb in normal state.

Is there a way to get the list of queries which are causing the tempdb issue? Or any way to check the queries ran last night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run this query as per your frequency and dump them into some table for later analysis..

```
SELECT
  sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id AS [SESSION ID]
  ,DB_NAME(database_id) AS [DATABASE Name]
  ,HOST_NAME AS [System Name]
  ,program_name AS [Program Name]
  ,login_name AS [USER Name]
  ,status
  ,cpu_time AS [CPU TIME (in milisec)]
  ,total_scheduled_time AS [Total Scheduled TIME (in milisec)]
  ,total_elapsed_time AS    [Elapsed TIME (in milisec)]
  ,(memory_usage * 8)      AS [Memory USAGE (in KB)]
  ,(user_objects_alloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Allocated FOR USER Objects (in KB)]
  ,(user_objects_dealloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Deallocated FOR USER Objects (in KB)]
  ,(internal_objects_alloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Allocated FOR Internal Objects (in KB)]
  ,(internal_objects_dealloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Deallocated FOR Internal Objects (in KB)]
  ,CASE is_user_process
             WHEN 1      THEN 'user session'
             WHEN 0      THEN 'system session'
  END         AS [SESSION Type], row_count AS [ROW COUNT]
FROM 
  sys.dm_db_session_space_usage
INNER join
  sys.dm_exec_sessions
ON  sys.dm_db_session_space_usage.session_id = sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id
```

I personally prefer  tracking this using extended events..Below is the way to track using extended events..You can see the full demo on [brentozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/tracking-tempdb-growth-using-extended-events/)

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [PublicToilet] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT [sqlserver].[database_file_size_change] (
    ACTION ( [sqlserver].[session_id], [sqlserver].[database_id],
    [sqlserver].[client_hostname], [sqlserver].[sql_text] )
    WHERE ( [database_id] = ( 2 )
            AND [session_id] > ( 50 ) ) ),
ADD EVENT [sqlserver].[databases_log_file_used_size_changed] (
    ACTION ( [sqlserver].[session_id], [sqlserver].[database_id],
    [sqlserver].[client_hostname], [sqlserver].[sql_text] )
    WHERE ( [database_id] = ( 2 )
            AND [session_id] > ( 50 ) ) )
ADD TARGET [package0].[asynchronous_file_target] (  SET filename = N'c:\temp\publictoilet.xel' ,
                                                    metadatafile = N'c:\temp\publictoilet.xem' ,
                                                    max_file_size = ( 10 ) ,
                                                    max_rollover_files = 10 )
WITH (  MAX_MEMORY = 4096 KB ,
        EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS ,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 1 SECONDS ,
        MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB ,
        MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE ,
        TRACK_CAUSALITY = ON ,
        STARTUP_STATE = ON );
GO
```

You may also want to check this link..

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029(v=sql.105).aspx

References:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13911/how-to-find-the-sql-statements-that-caused-tempdb-growth

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)

Select the Metric as "Temp DB Memory Used (KB)" and Statistic as "Max".
Then I found the query that kill TempDB.

Hope this help

[image]